# NHibernate: No persister for NHibernate.Criterion.SqlFunctionProjection

Tags: nhibernate

I am using NHibernate version 2.0.0.4000.

In one of my queries I wanted to make use of the sql function dateadd to add a number of days. This wasn't registered so I created my own dialect and registered the function as follows:

```
RegisterFunction("adddays", 
    new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.DateTime, 
    "dateadd(dd, ?1, ?2)"));
```

The registration gets hit and seems to work fine. I use the function in a DetachedCriteria query as follows:

```
...
Restrictions.LtProperty("DateColumn1"
    Projections.SqlFunction("adddays", NHibernateUtil.DateTime,
        Projections.Constant(days),
        Projections.Property("DateColumn2"))
...
```

The criteria is returned from a method and passed of to another query. Upon the execution of the final query I get the following exception:

```
NHibernate.MappingException was caught
  Message="No persister for: NHibernate.Criterion.SqlFunctionProjection"
  Source="NHibernate"
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName,
            Boolean throwIfNotFound)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName)
       ...
```

None of the blog posts that I have seen mention this problem. Can anybody help?

Cheers in advance.
Nige.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it.

The problem was caused by my usage elsewhere of `Restrictions.Eq` rather than `Restrictions.EqProperty`. The former does not have an overload for `(IProjection,IProjection)` and so was treating the second projection as an object and passing it to a persister.

Thanks to anyone who investigated this.
Nigel.

Answer (score 1):

For No Persister exception in nhibernet solution is

just give a right click on the respective hbm file ->Properties->change the type Build Action-> to Embedded Resource

with the above step application will working fine